# flask running 2 development servers in kubernetes pod causing issues

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flask

I have created a Flask app with a login feature using Firebase which works when run from my terminal.

I created a docker image which also works as intended.

But when I create a deployment on K8s(Using Minikube) and create a nodeport service thats where I start to get problems. My log in page will not allow me to log in anymore but I can create an account which shows up on my Firebase console.

Checking the pod logs I can see that it is running a dev server on both the localhost and the pod ip.

```
 * Serving Flask app 'server.py'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://10.244.0.31:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

At first I thought nothing of it but I then went to create a production deployment using gunicorn and set the workers to 2. I got the exact same issue!

Is there a reason why flask is running the dev server on localhost and the pod ip and how can I stop it?

Additional info: I can get the behaviour I want from the app if I use this command to port forward but I want to use a NodePort service instead.
`kubectl port-forward deployment/flask-web-app 5000:5000`

Here is a link to the flask app which also has the dockerfile I created.

https://github.com/Bobbins228/watering-system-web-app/blob/main/server.py

This is also a Gist of my deployment config for k8s.

https://gist.github.com/Bobbins228/7e56adb842de6103bf6d5135ba6e1144

Checking again I changed the configuration of the python file to...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True)
```

And when I run it locally I get 2 ips.

```
 * Serving Flask app 'server.py'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.1.49:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

When I click on the localhost link the app works as intended but the local ip address one has the same issues as above.

Comment: share your python file which config the flask app to check host config, just for ref : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/flask-cloud-shell/01oci-flask-shell-summary.htm

Comment: I added a link to my python file and a gist of the deployment yaml file

Comment: got that, thanks and you have nodeport service might be accessing service with NodeIP:Nodeport correct ?

Comment: I updated the gist to include the service file https://gist.github.com/Bobbins228/7e56adb842de6103bf6d5135ba6e1144#file-service-yaml

Comment: thanks looks good..! what error are you having when hit the node port ?

Comment: What do you mean? when I visit the website and try to log in?

Comment: The output you're showing here seems normal to me, including the multiple `Running on ...` lines.  When you say the login page doesn't work, what URL are you trying to access, and what is the actual error?  Is the Service correctly attached to the application Pod(s)?

Comment: Thats one of the issues there are actually no errors even on the website! When you enter your login details the page just refreshes and the text boxes become empty. I checked the pod's logs and the post requests are being made successfully ```172.17.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2023 14:21:47] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
172.17.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2023 14:21:47] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 302 -
172.17.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2023 14:21:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2023 14:21:47] "GET /static/css/css5.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: I have managed to get rid of the second development server. It was created because I had set the host port in the run command when creating the docker image. upon removing it there is now just one server running on http://127.0.0.1:5000. Problem is now I cant access the website at all with NodePort